# Navbar keeps disappearing only on one page on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having an issue on my website where on the mobile version, when you click the hamburger menu, you see the animation of it moving then when it gets to 100% it disappears. It is fine on every other section of the site.

You can test it here: https://www.robertcalamari.com/pages/paintings.html

Here is the javascript:

**paintings.js:**

```
function printPaintingSections(data){
    var imgsize = 150;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("img-holder")[0].offsetWidth;
    var y = document.getElementsByClassName("img-holder")[0].offsetHeight;
    numberofpics = data.allpaintings.length;

    if(window.innerWidth < 960){
        imgsize = (window.innerWidth/2.5);
    }else{
        imgsize = y/5;
    }

    allPaintings = data.allpaintings;
    
    
    for(let i in data.allpaintings){
            // console.log("Name: " + data.allpaintings[data.allpaintings.length - i - 1].name + " | Price: " + data.allpaintings[data.allpaintings.length - i - 1].price);
            var currPainting = data.allpaintings[data.allpaintings.length - i - 1];
            if(currPainting.issold == 1){
                issold = '<div id="paintingsold-' + i + '" class="paintingsold" style="color:white;">$' + currPainting.price + '</div>';
            }else if(currPainting.issold == 2){
                issold = '<div id="paintingsold-' + i + '" class="paintingsold" style="color:red;">SOLD</div>';
            }
        
            document.getElementsByClassName("img-holder")[0].innerHTML+= `<div class="img-background" id="img-background-` + i + `" style="width:` + imgsize + `px;height:` + imgsize + `px;" onclick="openPaintingsPage('` + currPainting.id + `')">
            ` + issold + `
            <img class="painting-img" id="painting-img-` + currPainting.id + `" style="width:` + imgsize + `px;height:` + imgsize + `px;" src="` + currPainting.img + `" > 
            </div>`;     
    }
    
    // setTimeout(function(){ 
    //     animateAllImages(data.allpaintings.length);
    //    }, 800);
}
```

**navbar.js:**

```
function openMenuBar(){
    if(menuBarIsOpen == false){
        document.getElementsByClassName("mobileonly")[0].classList.add("rotate180");
        setTimeout(() => {
            document.getElementsByClassName("mobileonly")[0].classList.remove("rotate180");            
        }, 300);
        document.getElementsByClassName("navbar")[0].style.width = "100%";
        document.getElementsByClassName("navbar")[0].style.right = "0";
        document.getElementsByClassName("navbar")[0].style.opacity = "1";        
        menuBarIsOpen = true;
    }else{
        document.getElementsByClassName("mobileonly")[0].classList.add("rotate180");
        setTimeout(() => {
            document.getElementsByClassName("mobileonly")[0].classList.remove("rotate180");            
        }, 300);
        document.getElementsByClassName("navbar")[0].style.width = "0";
        document.getElementsByClassName("navbar")[0].style.right = "-100px";
        menuBarIsOpen = false;
    }
}
```

**Relevant CSS**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 550px) {
    .navbar{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
        width: 0;
        opacity: 0;
        height: 68px;
        padding-top: 0px;
        padding-bottom: 0px;
        position: absolute;
        top:68px;
        right:-100px;
        background-color: #181818;
        transition: width 0.2s linear;
        z-index:2;
    }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////

@media only screen and (max-width: 960px) {

    .container{
        height: 100vh !important;
    }

    .painting-scroll {
        display: none;
    }

    .img-holder{
        flex-direction:row;
    }

    .paintings-page-description{
        padding-top: 1px;
    }

    .img-background{
        padding: 18px;
        margin: auto;
        background-color: #18181800;
    }

    .paintings-page{
        left: 2%;
        max-width: 95%;
        max-height: 89%;
        top: calc(50% - (95%/2));
        height: 775px;
    }

    .paintings-page-right{
        padding-left:0;
        padding-bottom: 79px;
        padding-top: 41px;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }

    .paintings-page-left{
        width: 100%;
        height: 7%;
    }

    .paintings-page-continue{
        bottom: -3px;
        right: 1px;
    }

    .paintings-page-header{
        font-size: 30px;
        padding-top:0px;
        width: 91%;
        line-height: 26px;
    }

    .paintings-page-price{
        bottom: 7px;
        right: 1px;
    }

    .paintings-page-artist{
        top: 69px;
        font-size: 12px;
        padding-bottom: 0px;
    }

    .paintings-page-material{
        padding-bottom: 0px;
        font-size: 12px;
    }

    .paintings-page-img-container{
        max-width: 560px;
        margin:auto;
        border: none;
        width: 78% !important;
        height: 78% !important;
        margin-top: 0px;
    }

    .paintings-page-size{
        padding-bottom: 341px !important;
        font-size: 12px;
    }

    .paintings-page-image{
        max-height: 500px;
    }

    .paintings-page-close{
        top:-11px;
        right:-4px;
    }

    .paintings-page-back{
        left: -69px;
        position: absolute;
        height: 44px;
        width: 160px;
        margin-top: 59px;
    }

    .paintings-page-next{
        right: 32px;
        position: absolute;
        height: 44px;
        width: 160px;
        margin-top: 59px;
    }

    .paintingssold{
        top: 26px;
        left: 26px;
    }

}
```

The only thing I can figure out is when I remove this line of code, the navbar will work again.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("img-holder")[0].innerHTML+= `<div class="img-background" id="img-background-` + i + `" style="width:` + imgsize + `px;height:` + imgsize + `px;" onclick="openPaintingsPage('` + currPainting.id + `')">
            ` + issold + `
            <img class="painting-img" id="painting-img-` + currPainting.id + `" style="width:` + imgsize + `px;height:` + imgsize + `px;" src="` + currPainting.img + `" > 
            </div>`;
```